# Display data from database using html encode(yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

I want to display the specific data from database using `<?= Html::encode() ?>`

Let say, i get the specific column of the model as below:

```
   <?php $model = ExampleModule::find()->select('anycolumn')->all(); ?>
```

And then, what  should i write to the `<?= Html::encode(anystatement) ?>`to display the values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can encode the single column result and ->all() return a collection fo models

so first you should access to single model, eg: assuming you obtain your collection  of models as an array

```
    <?php $model = ExampleModule::find()->select('anycolumn')->asArray->()all(); ?>
```

you can encode the single column result for the first model this way

```
    <?= Html::encode($model[0]['your_column']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all data first .

First step

```
<?php $model = ExampleModule::find()->select('anycolumn')->asArray()->all(); ?>
```

Second step

```
<?= Html::encode($model[0]['anycolumn']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `ExampleModule::find()->select('anycolumn')->all()` returns an array of records.

If you want to get first found record you need to use

```
<?php
$model = ExampleModule::find()->select('anycolumn')->one();
?>
```

Then

```
<?= Html::encode($model->anycolumn) ?>
```

Or if you want to display all records:

```
<?php
foreach (ExampleModule::find()->select('anycolumn')->all() as $model) {
    echo Html::encode($model->anycolumn) . '<br>';
}
?>
```